# Does anyone recognize these rockets, and their location?

Tags: rockets, identify-this-object

I clicked an advertisement in the sidebar of an Economist article and it took me to this infomercial from Mitsubishi Heavy Industry Group's *Spectra* website [How new technology is democratizing access to space](https://spectra.mhi.com/how-new-technology-is-democratizing-access-to-space)

Does anyone recognize these rockets, and their location?

Original can be viewed at the website linked above, here's what the page looks like with a watermarked version from [pixtastock](https://www.pixtastock.com/photo/28630206) Thanks to @JCRM [for the tip](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/does-anyone-recognize-these-rockets-and-their-location?noredirect=1#comment116787_36721)

[image: Mitsubishi Heavy Industry "How new technology is democratizing access to space"]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like JAXA's [H-II launch vehicle](https://global.jaxa.jp/projects/rockets/h2/index.html) to me.

I believe we're looking at the business ends of the core stage (right) and the one of the side boosters (left).

The H-II was retired in 1999 and superseded by the H-IIA, so these stacks are on display at [JAXA's Tsukuba Centre](https://global.jaxa.jp/about/centers/tksc/) - the vehicle and booster can be seen in the aerial image on the homepage. [Here's](https://a0.cdn.japantravel.com/photo/13385-77630/800!/ibaraki-jaxa-space-center-in-tsukuba-77630.jpg) another angle.

[image]

Comment: Holy blown out image, batman...

Answer (score 31):

Just to add to @Jack's correct answer you can see the rockets in Ibaraki, Japan via [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@36.0700201,140.130197,244a,35y,180.45h,39.82t/data=!3m1!1e3), you can see the two rockets (and even make out the red rocket part):

[image]

<sub>(Just FYI - I screenshotted your image (just the rocket part), saved as a .jpg, then did a [reverse Google Image Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voFuq.gif) which quickly found the rockets.)</sub>

Comment: I wonder if they didn't have room to install both boosters or if they didn't have a spare booster casing for the display?

Comment: @RussellBorogove - Good question - I've Googled around a bit and can't find why there's just one.  However, I would bet if they did have access to both boosters, they'd have them both displayed. I can't find anything about one exploding/being lost for some reason, but I suspect there's just one in existence now (or at least in good enough condition to display).

Comment: @BruceWayne Or they wanted people to be able to see one side of the main rocket without it being obscured by the booster.